# Error {“readyState”:4,“status”:404, “statusText”:“not found”} in SP Online Delete ListItem

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, delete

I am not able to delete the list item using the `getitembyid(ID)` method using SP Online REST call. I am making a call to `deleteitem(murl)` where `murl` ===>

```
   for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; 
       i++) 
        {  
         var item = data.d.results[i];  
             ID = item.ID;
       ID = item.ID
      var murl =  
  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
 "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Posts_Testing')
   /getItemById("+ID+")";
.....
     }
```

Below is the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
  function deleteItem(murl) {
  alert(' inside delete fun');
    alert(murl);
    $.ajax({
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
   murl,
     type: "DELETE",
    headers: {
   "accept": 
   "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "X-RequestDigest": 
   $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "If-Match": "*"
       },
     success: function (data) {
     },
        error: function (error) {
       alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
     });
   }
          return true;
    }
</script>
```

I am getting error:

[image: ErrorinRESTAPI-delete-call]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your call is wrong.

type should be `Post`

and there should be a property for `"X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"`

Overall ajax call should be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: <endpoint for item>,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-ReuqestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.error('error');
    }
});
```

Check out this post [CRUD Operations in SharePoint Using REST API - Delete Operations](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api-delete-operations/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is better to use recycle() method, because later you can recover deleted items from recycle bin.

```
function DeleteListItem (listName, itemId) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: encodeURI(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemId + ")/recycle()"),
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        }
    });
}
```